# Lambda function access by RDS trigger creates connection lost

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, mysql-workbench, database-trigger, amazon-aurora

I created 2 tables in RDS aurora:

1. `test-table` in aurora db with values id(PK), tasknumber, status , contactid(FK)
2. `contact-table` in same db with values contactid(PK), email, phone

I created a trigger in 'test-table' that whenever a 'status' changes, the trigger should call AWS-Lambda ARN.

The Lambda function and Aurora has all the permissions, and security cleared, still on testing from Lambda I get below image error and on updating the 'status' field manually in aurora(via Workbench Sql query) it shows:

> Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
>
> ERROR 2013: 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query

I have attached my Lambda Node.Js code too.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({ region: 'us-east-1' });
const mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({

  host: 'correct value',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'correct value',
  port: correct value,
  database: 'correct value'

});
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
  var fk = event.contact_id;
  console.log('FOREIGN KEY=', fk)

  con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var sql = `SELECT * FROM db.contacts where contact_id=${fk}`

    con.query(sql, function(err, result) {
     if (err) throw err;
     var email = result[0].email;
     console.log(email);

     var sns = new AWS.SNS();
    var params = {
     Message: email,
      Subject: "Test SNS From Lambda",
     TopicArn: "arn:correct value"
   };

      sns.publish(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); 
        else {
          console.log(data);
          callback(null, 'Success');
        }
      });

    });
  });
};
```

- [Image1ErrorMySqlWorkbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsQID.png)
- [Image2ErrorLambdaaws](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UB4hE.png)

Also followed for NodeJs package: https://github.com/isaacs

Comment: As a solution:
- I increased timeout tenure for Lambda function
- Increased memory for Lambda
- Security Group Config: 
MYSQL/Aurora
TCP
3306
0.0.0.0/0
- Corrected IAM policy, the RDS and Lambda has same IAM

Comment: MySql Trigger works when the conditions don't met. I guess that's logical as at that time it does not has to call Lambda ARN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to close the connection if you want the instant response otherwise it will take the default time to close the connection, please let me know if makes sense

Comment: Please can you elaborate, I could not understand.

Comment: con.query(sql, function(err, result) { if (err) throw err; var email = result[0].email; console.log(email); try to close the connection after fetching the data

Comment: con.end()  - still giving the same issue. Error is 'connect ETIMEOUT'

Comment: are they in the same vpc?

Comment: No, they were not previously. Just corrected it, still getting below error:
>Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the >database.
>ERROR 2013: 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Comment: The only thing i can see here is the inbound rules for database,  may be the rds instance was allowed only from specific ip, try changing that to allow lambda vpc subnet might help